# How to query nested doc of nested doc where email matches example@gmail.com

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

A user has many payments, a payment has many debtors, a debtor belongs to a user.

I am trying to find a users payments that relate to another particular user.

I have a query which gets a users payments, populated with all the debtors and user information for each debtor.

```
const user_1 = await this.userModel
        .findOne({email: "geoffery.brown@gmail.com"})
        .populate({path: 'payments', populate: {path: 'debtors', populate: {path: 'user'}}})
```

which returns a something like this:

```
{
    "payments": [
        {
            "debtors": [
                {
                    "_id": "5a9531b0de918e42c94947cc",
                    "amount": 15,
                    "user": {
                        "payments": [],
                        "created_at": "2018-02-27T10:14:39.847Z",
                        "_id": "5a95300388740142774f49c9",
                        "first_name": "John",
                        "last_name": "Smith",
                        "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5a9531b0de918e42c94947cd",
                    "amount": 10,
                    "user": {
                        "payments": [],
                        "created_at": "2018-02-27T10:14:39.847Z",
                        "_id": "5a95302188740142774f49ca",
                        "first_name": "Joe",
                        "last_name": "Blogs",
                        "email": "joe.blogs@hotmail.com",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2018-02-27T10:23:31.561Z",
            "_id": "5a9531b0de918e42c94947ce",
            "date": "2018-02-26T10:54:36.167Z",
            "reference": "Food",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "created_at": "2018-02-27T10:14:39.847Z",
    "_id": "5a952fc488740142774f49c8",
    "first_name": "Geoffery",
    "last_name": "Brown",
    "email": "geoffery.brown@gmail.com",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want to have my mongo query be able to filter the debtors where `email === "john.smith@gmail.com"`

Is this possible with my current mongodb structure?

Comment: Something like `.populate({path: 'payments', populate: {path: 'debtors', populate: {path: 'user’,match: { email: "john.smith@gmail.com" }}}})`

Comment: @Veeram it hasn't actually worked. It is still returning the other debtors but truncates the user data. I need to truncate the who debtor object from the array of debtors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such support is available in mongoose populate. You can use aggregate like below in 3.4.

Similar concept as  to populate but all the heavy lifting is done in single server call inside aggregation framework.

`$lookup` stage is used to pull data from different referenced collections.

`$unwind` stage to flatten the structure for subsequent lookups.

`$group` stages each to push debtors into payments and payments array into main document.

```
this.userModel.aggregate([
    {"$match":{"email": "geoffery.brown@gmail.com"}}, 
    {"$lookup":{
      "from":"payments", // name of the collection
      "localField":"payments",
      "foreignField":"_id",
      "as":"payments"
    }},
    {"$unwind":"$payments"},
    {"$lookup":{
      "from":"debtors", // name of the collection
      "localField":"payments.debtors",
      "foreignField":"_id",
      "as":"debtors"
    }},
    {"$project":{"payments.debtors":0}},
    {"$unwind":"$debtors"},
    {"$lookup":{
      "from":"users", // name of the collection
      "localField":"debtors.user",
      "foreignField":"_id",
      "as":"debtors.user"
    }},
    {"$unwind":"$debtors.user"},
    {"$match":{"debtors.user.email":"john.smith@gmail.com"}},
    {"$group":{
      "_id":{id:"$_id",payment_id:"$payments._id"},
      "created_at":{"$first":"$created_at"},
      "first_name":{"$first":"$first_name"},
      "last_name": {"$first":"$last_name"},
      "email": {"$first":"$email"},
      "payments":{"$first":"$payments"},
      "debtors":{"$push":"$debtors"}
    }},
    {"$addFields":{"payments.debtors":"$debtors"}},
    {"$project":{"debtors":0}},
    {"$group":{
      "_id":"$_id.id",
      "created_at":{"$first":"$created_at"},
      "first_name":{"$first":"$first_name"},
      "last_name": {"$first":"$last_name"},
      "email": {"$first":"$email"},
      "payments":{"$push":"$payments"}
    }}
    ]).exec(function() {...})
```

Comment: That has done the trick thanks @Veeram. A bit more complicated than I was hoping but perhaps my db is not structured as well as it should be.

Comment: Yeah. mongodb in general works well with atmost two level. The more deep the data structure is the more complicated the query, aggregation and updates become.